# Where are new Google calendar reminders stored?

Tags: android, api, calendar

Google calendar has introduced calendar reminders had a new feature.
Where are this new reminders stored?
I have searched at com.google.android.calendar data and doesn't.
Also searched at com.android. providers.calendar data and can't locate it.
I assume that are part of a private API, due to the reminders sends that aren't synced with Google calendar (web)

Comment: I was looking the same thing but it seems it doesn't exist a public API to access :/

Comment: The Matrix, I think you should add your EDIT comment as an answer, although it's not a complete solution, it sort of clarifies the situation

Comment: By the way, here's the issue where people are asking for API access for the new reminders: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4437&q=new%20reminders&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner
Please star it hoping it gets some attention

Comment: Reminders database resides is in the Google Play Services database folder. The question now is if it exists a Play Services API for that and the answer is "it doesn't exists at this moment" :(